# error: no class roots are found in the JDK path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64

Tags: kotlin, ubuntu-16.04

I  install kotlin and JDK in Ubuntu 16.04 by following the guidelines here https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html

After that created a file Hello.kt,

but when I run this,

`kotlinc Hello.kt -include-runtime -d Hello.jar`

I got this error

`error: no class roots are found in the JDK path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64`

This is the first time of me so basically I don't have any idea what to do.

Do you have?

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't have Kotlin in the base repositories, so the default Java installation is unlikely to be Kotlin-aware.

If you use SDKMAN! to install Kotlin, you probably need to use the SDKMAN! installation of Java as well.

```
sdk install java
sdk install kotlin
```

Verify that you are not using the Ubuntu-stock Java...

```
$ which java
~/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/java ## you should see '.sdkman' in the path here
```

Comment: thanks!  Saw this and thought it was an open issue:
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/error-no-class-roots-are-found-in-the-jdk-path-usr-lib-jvm-java-9-openjdk-amd64/7516/3

So glad it was this simple.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

For me, this arose because `brew upgrade` removed one jdk version in favor of another.

Gradle, meanwhile, had cached the reference to the jdk version.

I resolved the issue by removing the gradle cache (`rm -r .gradle`) and then recompiling.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with your java version.Remove the existing jdk and reinstall the latest one and set the jdk path properly it will resolve your problem.

Comment: That's the latest.. incase its not in the path, how to do that? where do I find the path?

Comment: Find the jdk installation directory,"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10" this my jdk path in windows pc.

Comment: I doing this on Ubuntu 06.04 release